# How to load an image ending with any file type extension in PHP using Regular Expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP program which scans a folder named `output` (which contains all image files in any format) for images. The image files are the screenshots of the output in terminal (I'm using Linux) of various Java programs. The image files are named according to the class name in which the `main()` function resides. So for example if the `main()` function resides inside the public `Example` class, then the output screenshot will be named `Example` with the extension of either `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png` or `.gif`. The PHP program has a front page which scans for Java files and lists them in an unordered list with links the user can click to go on the next page. The next page reads the particular file and displays the source code along with the output screenshot. Now since I'm using Fedora and Fedora takes screenshots in `png` format, that is quite easy like:

```
echo '<img src="' . $file_name . '".png>'
```

But what if someone uploads a Java program with the output screenshot in any format? (`jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, `gif`). How to then load the appropriate image file since I don't know what the extension will be?

I have an answer to use `foreach` loop and read through every image file there is within the output folder and then use an `if` condition for checking the appropriate file names with the various extensions but I think it will not be a very good programming practice.

I generally try to avoid conditions while programming and use more mathematical approach cause that gives me the challenge I need and I feel my code looks different and unique compared to others' but I don't seem to make it work this time.

I'm feeling that this can be done using regular expressions but I don't know how to do it. I know regular expressions but I'm clueless to even how to use them for this. Any answer to not use regular will be appreciated but I want to make this work using regular expressions because in that way I'll also add a little bit of knowledge to  my regular expression concepts.

Thanks.

Comment: Why outputs are stored as screenshot *(and note as text)*? What a crazy idea! Why you don't know what is the extension?

Comment: Because anyone can add a source file for any language and also the output will be in an image file which can have any extension.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to MM's that uses RegEx:

```
 function getImageFilename ($basename, $directory) {

    $filenames = scandir($directory);
    $pattern = "/^" . $basename . "\.(jpeg|png|jpg|gif)$/";

    foreach($filenames as $filename) {
        preg_match($pattern, $filename, $matches);
        if($matches) {
            return $filename;
        }
     }

     return false;
 }
```

You can't avoid using a loop. You either loop through the possible file names and check for their existence, or you get a list of all the files in the directory and loop through them whilst performing a pattern match.

If there aren't a lot of files in the directory then this function might perform better because it only needs to call the OS once (to get a list of the files in the directory), whereas asking the OS to check for file existence multiple times requires multiple system calls. (I think that's right...)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, you could check if the file exists with that extension (assuming you won't have multiple images with the same name but different extensions):

```
function get_image($file_name) {
    if (file_exists($file_name . '.png')) {
        return $file_name . '.png';
    } elseif (file_exists($file_name . '.jpg')) {
        return $file_name . '.jpg';
    } elseif (file_exists($file_name . '.gif')) {
        return $file_name . '.gif';
    }

    return false;
}

echo '<img src="' . get_image($file_name) . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the pattern as an *or* list of the various extensions:

```
$pattern = '/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i';
```

We are also making sure this is an extension by including the match with a dot (escaped) and making sure it's at the end of the string ($). The "i" at the end of that enables case-insensitive matching, so that the regex still picks up GIF or JPG in filenames.

After that, the test is fairly simple:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $filename)) {
   echo "File $filename is an image";
}
```

Putting it together in an example, you can see:

```
$filename = 'test.png';
$pattern = '/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i';

if (preg_match($pattern, $filename)) {
   echo "File $filename is an image";
}
```

https://eval.in/618651

Whether you want to wrap that in a function, is up to you, as you would have to decide what to return in case the filename does not match one of the extensions provided.

Also note that the test is based on the extension *only* and not on the content.